# Is my program losing precision in counting clicks per second?

Tags: java, time, jbutton, actionlistener

I made a ticker which will show the average number of clicks per second which will 
 refresh every .1 second. It will count the clicks for the past 4 seconds.

Is there any chance that I am losing precision? Because my rates max to 6 and I would 
 presume to have a higher rate from tapping in gaming experience.

```
// Frame not shown

 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class Ticker extends JPanel

 { private  int d, count, rate, x; private int[] array;
  private JLabel l; 

  public Ticker()

     {  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

     rate = x = 0;
  // JPanel p = new JPanel();

     setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

     JButton b = new JButton("Click");
     b.addActionListener(new Listener());
     b.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
     add(b);

     l = new JLabel("a");
     l.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
     add(l);

     Timer  t = new Timer(100, new Listener2());
     t.start();

     array = new int[40];

     for (int k = 0; k < 40; k++)
        array[k] = 0;

  }

  private class Listener implements ActionListener

  {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

     {
        count++;
     }

  }

  private class Listener2 implements ActionListener
  {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {  
        if (x > 39)
           x = 0;

        array[x] = count;

        count = 0;

        x++;


        for (int i : array)
        { rate += i;  }

        l.setText("" + (int)(rate/4.0));
        rate = 0;
     //   System.out.println((int)(x) +"     " + array[(x-1)]);
     }
  }

  }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Remember that if you're clicking rapidly, and going through the standard APIs, the system may interpret the second click as doubleclick rather than click.

Comment: (to keshlam's comment) Thanks for the note                        Usually I believe that most modern processors are capable of handling much more information before they lag even to the milliseconds... I was able scan thousands of words within the flick of eye in some programs...

Comment: Processor capability, and driver capability, and peripheral capablility, are very different things.

Comment: I think you are losing something. I can get it up to 6/second. But then I used b.doClick() to press the button 10 times/second and that worked. But when I start clicking on top of the 10/second, I can only get it up to 11/second instead of 16/second. Maybe instead of using ActionPerformed you should change the program to use a MouseListener and count MousePressed and MouseReleased?

Comment: To (keshlam and Roy)   Thank you for the suggestion, I shall try out MouseListener to see if it improves on accuracy, I am worrying if strong clicks on an array is losing speed.

Comment: I tried MouseListener and couldn't get my clicks/second any higher.  Before you go much further, google "how fast can i click the mouse" and you'll get a lot of links to test how fast you're actually clicking.